# Trigger on Lightning List VIew

Tags: lightning, list-view

I have one requirement where I need to write one trigger on Lightning list view that shows validation when multiple records are updated with same value.

FOr example:

There is one Lightning List View for Account.
User selects multiple account by checking checkboxes
Now he updates the Name for selected accounts and gives new name as "newaccount"
then trigger should get fired and only one account should be updated with new name that is 'newaccount' and for rest of other accounts an error should be displayed on that view only

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid duplicate, Duplicate Rules might help you.

Comment: Hey Rahul thanks for reply. any possibility with trigger

Comment: Why do you want it only for Listview? Trigger run for every CRUD operation, It has nothing to do with List view.

Comment: If you can brief about the approach as to how should i go about it

Comment: @AmitRajput did you figure this out?